# How to check Storage Size of local-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using react-native-local-mongodb in one of my react native mobile application. What will be the maximum data can be stored in local-mongodb? How should I get the storageSize of local-mongodb on mobile device?

Comment: I'd assume you can just check the amount of free space available on the device and go from there? As by the looks of it, react-native-local-mongodb is simply using a file on the file system.

Comment: When I'm importing a huge chunk of JSON data in the application. It is giving me this error. `Error: database or disk is full (code 13)`. So I'm wondering how should I Check the capacity of the local-mongodb?

Comment: I realize it might be obvious, but how large is the file and how much free space is left on the device?

Comment: I'm checking it on android emulator. It is showing free space of around 54 MB. My file is CSV file I'm converting it into JSON by using  RNFS and papaparse. It contains a record of 50000 rows and 7 columns.